# SQL - Select Rows where Column is different on a corresponding record

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT
    RecordType = 7
    ,plc.PurchaseLogID
    ,pl.StoreID
    ,pl.UserID
    ,pl.ContractPurchaseID
    ,pl.ShoppingCartID
    ,PaymentDue = tm.tran_end_time
    ,PaymentMade = NULL
    ,pl.PurchaseWith
    ,pl.setupfee
    ,pl.FeeType
    ,pl.ProductID
    ,pl.PackageID
    ,ItemDescription = pl.PackageName
    ,CardType = NULL
    ,PaymentTransactionId = NULL
    ,PaymentStatus = NULL
    ,PaymentAmount = 
      CASE
        WHEN pl.onAccount = 1 THEN -util.ToDecimal172(pl.PurchaseAmount)
        ELSE util.ToDecimal172(pl.PurchaseAmount)
      END
    ,PaymentSalesTax = 
      CASE
        WHEN pl.onAccount = 1 THEN -util.ToDecimal172(pl.SalesTaxAmt)
        ELSE util.ToDecimal172(pl.PurchaseAmount)
      END
    ,RefundTransactionId = NULL
FROM
    [cdc].[dbo_PurchaseLog_CT] plc WITH (NOLOCK)    
    INNER JOIN [cdc].[lsn_time_mapping] tm WITH (NOLOCK)  ON plc.__$Start_lsn = tm.Start_lsn
    INNER JOIN dbo.purchaselog pl WITH (NOLOCK) ON plc.Purchaselogid = pl.purchaselogid
    INNER join StoreSet s ON pl.StoreID = s.Storeid
WHERE 
    tm.tran_end_time >= @fromDate
    AND tm.tran_end_time < @todate
    AND plc.__$operation = 4
    AND plc.DELETED IS NULL
    AND pl.RefundID IS NULL
```

So my issue... I am working with a CDC Table, and here are some of the columns that I am concerned with...

```
__$start_lsn             __$end_lsn      __$seqval             __$operation __$update_mask      ID       Deleted    
0x0025025900002F0B0013      NULL        0x0025025900002C010003         3        0x000008010000  41183961    NULL    
0x0025025900002F0B0013      NULL        0x0025025900002C010003         4        0x000008010000  41183961    1
```

In my Stored Proc, I need to only do the SELECT where the $operation = 4 AND Deleted = 1 where the corresponding ($operation 3, based on the $start_lsn && ID) has Deleted = NULL.

I am not sure how far away I am from achieving this... Any hints? Thanks guys!

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is ***NOT RECOMMENDED*** to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    RecordType = 7
    ,plc.PurchaseLogID
    ,pl.StoreID
    ,pl.UserID
    ,pl.ContractPurchaseID
    ,pl.ShoppingCartID
    ,PaymentDue = tm.tran_end_time
    ,PaymentMade = NULL
    ,pl.PurchaseWith
    ,pl.setupfee
    ,pl.FeeType
    ,pl.ProductID
    ,pl.PackageID
    ,ItemDescription = pl.PackageName
    ,CardType = NULL
    ,PaymentTransactionId = NULL
    ,PaymentStatus = NULL
    ,PaymentAmount = 
      CASE
        WHEN pl.onAccount = 1 THEN -util.ToDecimal172(pl.PurchaseAmount)
        ELSE util.ToDecimal172(pl.PurchaseAmount)
      END
    ,PaymentSalesTax = 
      CASE
        WHEN pl.onAccount = 1 THEN -util.ToDecimal172(pl.SalesTaxAmt)
        ELSE util.ToDecimal172(pl.PurchaseAmount)
      END
    ,RefundTransactionId = NULL
FROM
    [cdc].[dbo_PurchaseLog_CT] plc WITH (NOLOCK)    
    INNER JOIN [cdc].[lsn_time_mapping] tm WITH (NOLOCK)  ON plc.__$Start_lsn = tm.Start_lsn
    INNER JOIN dbo.purchaselog pl WITH (NOLOCK) ON plc.Purchaselogid = pl.purchaselogid
    INNER join StoreSet s ON pl.StoreID = s.Storeid
    --NEW CODE HERE ***
    INNER JOIN [cdc].[dbo_PurchaseLog_CT] plc2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON plc2.[__$start_lsn] = plc.[__$start_lsn] AND plc2.PurchaseLogID = plc.PurchaseLogID
WHERE 
    tm.tran_end_time >= @fromDate
    AND tm.tran_end_time < @todate
    --NEW CODE HERE ***
    AND (plc.__$operation = 4 AND plc.DELETED = 1)
    AND (plc2.[__$operation] = 3 AND plc2.Deleted IS NULL)
    --AND plc.__$operation = 4
    AND plc.DELETED IS NULL
    AND pl.RefundID IS NULL
```

It seems that adding an INNER JOIN to itself, joining on those 2 columns I specified, seems to have worked. I am going to run through several tests, but it seems like this might have done the trick. Thanks for anyone who might have been looking at this for me!